# java - print image code not working when it is deployed in linux - cent-os server

Tags: java, file, printing, centos

Following code is working fine when it is running on windows, but if this is deployrd in server and access through windows system it throws Runtime Exception "**No printer services available.**". is there is any problem in this code or can you suggest any alternatives

```
 package com.rajsoft.CAF.APController;

 import java.io.FileInputStream;

 import javax.print.Doc;
 import javax.print.DocFlavor;
 import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
 import javax.print.PrintService;
 import javax.print.PrintServiceLookup;
 import javax.print.SimpleDoc;
 import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
 import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
 import javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies;

 public class SamplePrint {
   static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
     PrintRequestAttributeSet pras = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
     pras.add(new Copies(1));
     PrintService pss[] =     PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, pras);
if (pss.length == 0)
  throw new RuntimeException("No printer services available.");
PrintService ps = pss[0];
System.out.println("Printing to " + ps);
DocPrintJob job = ps.createPrintJob();
//FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:/SignImage.GIF");
 FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("C:/SignImages/Hyderabad.GIF");
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fin, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.GIF, null);
job.print(doc, pras);
fin.close();
   }
 }
```

Comment: This: `"C:/SignImages/Hyderabad.GIF"` URI maybe?

Comment: in server i have replaced C: with /root and file is there in root.

Comment: it shows "No printer services available" exception. but printer is there and work fine in local windows jdk system

Comment: ? Executing on the client or server ?

Comment: project is developing using eclipse in winXP system, when i run in local works fine...but if the package deployed in server its not working(not detecting printer/even default printer also)

Comment: Well, I'm going to go out on a limb and say ... your server doesn't have a printer configured.

Comment: @Brian Roach for your information ....on that same server php based printing codes are worked...even general text files are printing using the same printer..."how a person expects such a simple logic is missing before quetioning"..printer is working properly

Comment: @THOSE WHO DOWNVOTED THIS can you please resolve it once
-------show ur idealogy,but not hidden idealogy

Answer (score 1):

I would guess its the flavor which you are requesting. Can you go with either null in flavor or simply call "lookupDefaultPrintService()" and see if any default service is returned for environment where you are invoking your code.